# Calculate roundness of a 3d particle?

Tags: geometry

I have a 3d particle given as an array of its vertices. How would I calculate roundness of the particle?

The Wikipedia only gives me a calculation for two dimensions and so do all other sources I found.

Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify: I am not looking for the sphericity, but the roundness, which is defined as "sharpness of the edges and corners.

Comment: Do you have a concept of center and a radius for your set of vertices?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the long wait. Yes I have the center and the radius for every vertex.